# no Callback in JSONP in an iframe with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, jsonp

I am using chrome.

I have an iframe in which i require to hit a url that supports jsonp.

so i used this code :

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    url: my_url.endpoint + '/login/v1/token' ,
    data: form_to_object("#signin_form"),
    context: window,
    // All Ajax calls to ABC are json

    // Response statuses other than 200 are caught in a timeout
    timeout: 10000, //10s

    // Handler for successful calls to ABC: calls that return with statusCode 200
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // console.log(data);
    alert("in access_token success");
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('error_flag')) {
        // Errors associated with this action are caught here:
        //    invalid_credentials, account_lockout, etc.
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("jump")) {
            ABC_show_frame(data.jump);
        } else {
            ABC_error_handler(data);
        }

        return;
    } 

    // Auth succeeded, we can log in the user
    GetUserProfile(data);
    // ABC_success_handler(data);
},

error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("In access_token error");
   if (data.hasOwnProperty("jump")) {
        ABC_show_frame(data.jump);
    } else {
        ABC_error_handler(data);
    }
}
});
```

Now this code does not attach a `callback=some_random_function_name` in the url that it generates after attaching the parameters of `data`.

like `https://abc/login/v1/token?username=ashish?password=abc` but no `callback`.

When i debug it line by line, it do call the url with `callback=something`, and it seems to work. (seems because may be sometime it does not attach even in debugging line by line.)

But when i just run it, it does not.

I think that may be the problem is a bug in jquery where it also has to attach `data` that it got from `form_to_object()` and may be that overrides the `callback` parameter. But that is just a guess.

What should i do ?

Comment: can this be because of `context : window`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a form and i was writing my own custom function that would be called when submit button of the form was clicked. In that function i was not stopping the event from propagating further. This lead to this weird errors.

```
$("form.ims.ajax").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do your stuff 
});
```

This solved the problem.