# How to create a URL from a string that replaces special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jsonp, special-characters

I am trying to make a jsonp request from inside an iframe. For some reason, it does not seem to work. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422125/no-callback-in-jsonp-in-an-iframe-with-data).

I am now trying to attach a `script` tag to the head of document. Now i need to generate `src` for that by adding parameters of an object, which may contain some special characters, that should be converted to their codes.

Is there any javascript function for that ? There must be in the jquery as it would be requiring the same for its jsonp or ajax calls.

If i have to write mine, what are the characters that i should convert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape strings to encode in URIs, use the encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() methods provided by Javascript API :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

See [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for detailed description.